# Page footer bounces up and down in view as content changes from jQuery DOM manipulations (add/remove/etc)

Tags: jquery, html, css, footer

My page **generates a lot of information dynamically** and uses jQuery to add/remove show/hide stuff in the DOM.

**This causes the page footer to bounce up and down** in the visible area of the screen as the page empties and loads new content.

```
<html>
    <head/>
    <body>
        <div id="content"/>
        <div id="footer"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Ideally the page footer would never be visible to the user without scrolling down** because the footer is distracting information that the user doesn't neeed to see unless he or she is looking for it.

**Should I position the footer dynamically with jQuery?**

Something like this?

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#footer").css('top', $(window).height() + 20);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting the CSS style 'min-height' on the 'content' div. This will allow you to push the footer down.

Bob

UPDATE: Here is an example:
http://jsbin.com/onasi/3/edit